# How to use NFC android api for devices without built-in NFC to communicate to ACR122U USB NFC Reader

Tags: android, nfc

is it possible to use NFC android api to communicate(read & write) to ACR122U external NFC reader.

see: [ACS ACR122 product specifications, sample apps and SDK](https://www.acs.com.hk/en/products/3/acr122u-usb-nfc-reader/)

Comment: you cant. You can only use `ACR122U` provided API.

Comment: this is noted sir.

Comment: what if the android device has NFC can I use the android NFC API to read and write data to ACR122 reader??  thanks

Comment: if the reader supports that operations - you can

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically it is possible, but you will need to tweak the Android firmware in order to adapt native NFC classes to work with external reader's API. That would require a custom ROM and some intermediate service running between native NFC and ACS hardware. You might take a look at [External NFC Service](https://github.com/skjolber/external-nfc-api) (by [ThomasRS](https://stackoverflow.com/users/459579/thomasrs)) as a close candidate suitable for this task. At the moment such an adaptation for custom ROMs is still a feature to implement.